# Sitecore Docker 10.2 on Windows 11

Tags: docker

I am trying to build Sitecore 10.2 for containers on my Windows 11 system.  Quite surprised when I got this message:

```
2017-10.2-20H2: Pulling from sxp/nonproduction/mssql-developer
image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform
```

I tried this on both the 2009 and ltsc2019 versions.

Is Windows 11 supported?  Has anyone tried using Sitecore containers with Windows 11?

Comment: Did you just install docker? Did you switch from Linux to Windows containers in the context menu of the app?

Comment: Yes, I installed docker, and ran "docker/getting-started" to make sure everything was running properly.  I went through the same steps on my Windows 10 VM running on top of Windows Server 2016, and did not encounter the error.

Comment: Windows 11 is not 20H2. You need to switch to hyperv isolation. Also, as stated above, you need to switch Docker to Windows mode, either via GUI or command line `$Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchWindowsEngine`

Comment: Thank you Mark.  Unfortunately, I may not have been clear.  Docker is running in Windows mode.  It looks like the issue here is that Sitecore does not have images for Windows 11.